# Components that inject `FirebaseApp` result in `No provider for FirebaseApp` message when running tests

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, firebase, karma-jasmine

When running `ng test` for my Angular app I get this error message for components that have `FirebaseApp` from `angularfire2` injected into the constructor.

[image]

I know for a regular service I would add that services to the `providers` array for that component spec file or if it was the `http` service I could add the `HttpClientModule` to the `imports` for that spec file but what do I do for Firebase?

Have tried doing this with no luck:

```
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase)
      ],
      declarations: [
        BlogPostComponent,
        HeaderComponent,
        FooterComponent
      ]
    }).compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(BlogPostComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    element = fixture.nativeElement;
    de = fixture.debugElement;

    fixture.detectChanges();
  }));
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to put the `FirebaseApp` into the providers barrel in your spec

```
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  providers: [FirebaseApp]
```

and if you need to stub out the values for that app you can do it like this

```
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  providers: [{ provide: FirebaseApp, useValue: someStubHere }]
```